# Update from Select Not Updating All Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to "ReSync" a table where I store details on EBay listings. To do this I use the EBay API to download all `Active` listings and then perform an update from a select to resync.

Schemas

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEbayListings](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ItemEbayURL] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [ListingDuration] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ListingType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ListingStatus] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SKU] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Used to store current Active listings download via API.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEbayProductStatus](
    [PRProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EbayListingId] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [DateListed] [datetime] NULL,
    [CostOfListing] [money] NULL,
    [DateOfStatusChange] [datetime] NULL,
    [CurrentStatus] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ListingEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEbayProductStatus] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PRProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Used to record EBay listings statuses and Listing end Dates (the table I want to ReSync)

Code

```
 UPDATE
    eps
SET
    eps.CurrentStatus = CASE WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.ListingStatus)) = 'Active' 
        THEN 'Listed' ELSE 'DeListed' END,
    eps.ListingEndDate = ebl.EndTime
FROM
    tblEbayProductStatus eps 
JOIN
    tblEbayListings ebl
ON
    eps.[PRProductId] = CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.SKU)) As INT)
```

After running this code, this `select`

```
SELECT eps.[CurrentStatus]
      ,ebl.[ListingStatus]
      ,ebl.sku
      ,eps.[PRProductId]
      ,eps.ListingEndDate 
      ,ebl.EndTime
  FROM [tblEbayListings] ebl
  Join [tblEbayProductStatus] eps 
  ON eps.[PRProductId] = ebl.sku
  Where ebl.ListingStatus = 'Active'
```

shows some get updated and some do not.....

```
+---------------+---------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| CurrentStatus | ListingStatus |  sku   | PRProductId | ListingEndDate   |     EndTime      |
+---------------+---------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| DeListed      | Active        | 160008 |      160008 | 2016-01-15 14:30 | 2016-03-05 14:50 |
| Listed        | Active        | 160010 |      160010 | 2016-03-05 14:50 | 2016-03-05 14:50 |
| Listed        | Active        | 160012 |      160012 | 2016-03-05 14:50 | 2016-03-05 14:50 |
| Listed        | Active        | 160016 |      160016 | 2016-03-05 14:50 | 2016-03-05 14:50 |
| DeListed      | Active        | 160017 |      160017 | 2016-01-18 06:42 | 2016-02-17 06:50 |
| Listed        | Active        | 160018 |      160018 | 2016-03-05 14:51 | 2016-03-05 14:51 |
| DeListed      | Active        | 160026 |      160026 | 2016-02-02 10:30 | 2016-03-05 14:26 |
+---------------+---------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
```

If I change the join on the select to

```
eps.[PRProductId] = CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.SKU)) As INT)
```

I get the exact same results.  If I change the join on the update to

```
eps.[PRProductId] = ebl.SKU
```

I get the exact same results.

I know I am missing something stupid as I have done this many times before but I cannot see what for looking.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Fred I would run the following to try and narrow down the problem:  SELECT UpdatedCurrentStatus = CASE WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.ListingStatus)) = 'Active' 
        THEN 'Listed' ELSE 'DeListed' END, eps.CurrentStatus
     UpdatedListingEndDate = ebl.EndTime ,eps.ListingEndDate
FROM
    tblEbayProductStatus eps 
JOIN
    tblEbayListings ebl
ON
    eps.[PRProductId] = CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.SKU)) As INT)

Comment: @KamranFarzami What am I meant to be looking for?  I am not sure how that will help me.

Comment: What I would do is look at the rows the select statement returns and see what is causing the update to not update the data. The logic of the select is identical to the update statement you have.

Comment: Your join conditions are different `eps.[PRProductId] = CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.SKU)) As INT)` versus `eps.[PRProductId] = ebl.sku`

Comment: @TT. My bad.  That is just where I suspected it could have been a join causing the problem.  I started out with the same joins but got the same problem.  I have tried all the different joins I could think of the one above is just the latest.

Comment: Any chance of storing `ebl.SKU` as an `INT` rather than a `VARCHAR(X)`? Seems like a bad table design to store integers that way. Also, the UPDATE statement has `CASE WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.ListingStatus)) = 'Active' ` and the SELECT statement has `Where ebl.ListingStatus = 'Active'`... It just doesn't make sense to have one way of handling the column in one query and another in another query... Make sure **absolutely everything** is handled **in the same way**.

Comment: @TT. `tblEbayListings` is just a temporary table created to store the listings as given by eBay.  All the values from the call are passed down as strings.  All the `TRIM`s and `CAST`'s are just me trying to get to the bottom of what was happening.  None of these made any difference. I deleted and recreated the table and re-downloaded the listing data twice.  On the 3rd try the problem disappeared.  I have absolutely no idea why..... Yet.

Comment: Well, I stared at your question three times now, I'm at the end of my wits. Without clear examples of input data that demostrate the problem of your queries there is nothing more I can tell. Anyway, I hope you do find the cause of the problem... GL!

Answer (score 0):

you try this update code

```
UPDATE
    tblEbayProductStatus
SET
    CurrentStatus = CASE WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.ListingStatus)) = 'Active' 
        THEN 'Listed' ELSE 'DeListed' END,
    ListingEndDate = ebl.EndTime
FROM
    tblEbayListings ebl
WHERE
    tblEbayProductStatus.[PRProductId] = CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(ebl.SKU)) As INT)
```

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.`  You are missing a table in the `FROM`